# Win10 50% of memory being used on nothing

Tags: windows-10, memory, gaming

Lately, I've noticed that my memory usage is nearing almost 100% while playing games such as Overwatch, Rocket League, and Fortnite, and it's causing my game to stutter and crash. After booting, I noticed that my memory usage is around 50% while it used to be only at <=30%. The processes that are displayed in Task Manager are no where close to adding up to 4GB of RAM usage.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've updated all of my drivers, and still no luck. I've looked around but most problems associated with this are associated with high non-paged pool memory and memory leaks.

Comment: Please show Task Manager's "Details" tab with the "Memory (private working set)"  , "Memory (shared working set)", and "Commit size" columns enabled. Sort by the Private working set.

Comment: Done. Added it to the post

Comment: Re _"After booting, I noticed that my memory usage is around 50% while it used to be only at <=30%"_ this is likely due to updates to Windows. Anyway the amount of RAM being used immediately after booting is not a generally useful bit of info. Most of the RAM that's in use immediately after booting can easily be reclaimed for other use, when it's needed.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate question! The scenario is very different. The accepted answer at the linked "duplicate question" is not an answer, it just suggests tools and reading for further investigation. Someone else there replied with an answer saying "I solved it", blaming uTorrent, but uTorrent does not show up in the process list here. Not every question similar to "Windows using too much RAM" is a duplicate! There are many, many scenarios that can cause this issue.

Comment: Re _"The processes that are displayed in Task Manager are no where close to adding up to 4GB of RAM usage"_: I don't know what's interesting about 4 GB here, but... the numbers displayed on TM's "Processes" screen are not the only RAM in use. They reflect only the process private working sets. btw you can get a sum of the size of all of those without doing a lot of addition: Open PerfMon , go to the Process object, select the Working Set - Private counter, and select the "Total" instance.

Comment: More to the point, though: RAMmap shows a not-unreasonable set of numbers, given that you are running 7 top-level Chrome windows and who knows how many Chrome processes. btw I don't know why your TM "Processes" tab is showing only 290 MiB for Chrome when your "Details" tab is obviously showing far more. Chrome is a known memory hog - I see 977 GiB of private WS just in the the Chrome processes I can see there. I would close all of your Chrome tabs and windows, then go to TM Details and make sure the Chrome procs are all actually gone, and then look again at your memory usage. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your computer seems to be in the virus. Run antivirus programs first and see whether the issue still exist.

Comment: I already ran Malwarebytes and nothing was detected. I also forgot to mention that Chrome is not the issue. I typically have Chrome closed while I play games, and my memory usage still hangs around 90%.

Comment: Well then! We need to start over, because at least one of your screen shots wasn't taken during your problem scenario. btw, so far it seems that you are not seeing a problem - you're just running a workload that needs lots of RAM, and Windows will let things use RAM if they need it. Windows' goal is to let processes use RAM _effectively_, which is not accomplished by hoarding it on the free list. RAMmap does account for all of the RAM. Task Manager's "Processes" tab shows only the processes' private working set so of course totaling those comes up "short".

Comment: @Peter.G The last thing modern malware wants to do is consume large amounts of RAM - they're trying to hide so they can continue to operate and steal your confidential data, not cause obvious resource issues.

Comment: Did you try poolmon?